# htaccess multiple rewrite cond

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I have a folder called `photo` and also have a htaccess file inside.

this is rule of the htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|png)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php?image=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA]
```

and if client pointed to http://site.com/photo/123.jpg?test
just equal http://site.com/photo/?image=123.jpg&test

and only works if extension is jpe?g or png.

but I discovered if just simply point to http://site.com/photo/123.jpg

and it also process with index.php

how can I add one more RewriteCond or other way to make rewrite only having query string

like:http://site.com/photo/123.jpg?test

Comment: It would be better to require secondary query string parameters in PHP.

Comment: That still need php process it